# docker exec error : rpc error: code = 13

Tags: docker

i have an error when i do docker exec -it containerID bash but the container is up.the container's mysql can access。 On the same computer (linux/centos7) two other containers are up and working well..

```
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:75: starting setns process caused \\\"fork/exec /proc/self/exe: no such file or directory\\\"\"\n"。
```

docker daemon log:(ps: disk storage capacity no problem)

```
Sep 05 14:54:06 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[2556]: time="2017-09-05T14:54:06.865115768+08:00" level=info msg="{Action=exec, Username=root, LoginUID=0, PID=27904}"
Sep 05 14:54:06 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[2556]: time="2017-09-05T14:54:06.866161932+08:00" level=info msg="{Action=start, Username=root, LoginUID=0, PID=27904}"
Sep 05 14:54:06 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[2556]: time="2017-09-05T14:54:06.866937477+08:00" level=info msg="{Action=resize, Username=root, LoginUID=0, PID=27904}"
Sep 05 14:54:06 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[2556]: time="2017-09-05T14:54:06.918521262+08:00" level=error msg="Error running exec in container: rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value \"oci runtime error: exec f
Sep 05 14:54:06 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[2556]: time="2017-09-05T14:54:06.918886936+08:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.24/exec/58ec220389fc476fc828523a62b8fb577815bdb6da85f77842f634091deea45b/resize returned error
Sep 05 14:54:07 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[2556]: [282B blob data]
```

docker info:
[root@localhost ~]# docker info

```
Containers: 22
 Running: 18
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
Images: 18
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-134909774-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 37.65 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 8.659 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 27.87 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.12 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host null bridge overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc docker-runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 2
CPUs: 24
Total Memory: 31.25 GiB
Name: localhost.localdomain
ID: I7D3:42F2:4C4T:AKKR:WPKR:TYQQ:ID4K:DWV7:WHZX:W64K:U3D6:O6IF
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

docker logs container-id have no errors.

Comment: what `docker-runc --version` yield ?

Comment: are you sure that "bash" is available in your container? try with sh: `docker exec -ti <container id or name> sh`

Comment: docker-runc is not installed.

Comment: docker exec -ti <container id or name> sh have the same errors.the container has up 4 weeks and works well all along。

Comment: Is this case look similiar to yours ? https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29794#issuecomment-285428034

Comment: Sounds like this bug: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25381. I am having a similar problem too :-(.